# aweber form submission on backend via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, aweber

I'm trying to submit an Aweber form from my signup page.

The Aweber submission works perfectly when I submit my page data via POST using the form action and submit button.

But with same values when I used **ajax**, the Aweber request callback gives an error below

```
302 Moved Temporarily
```

Has anybody faced same issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Not the same issue, but do you know where it moved to? When you do a form post back it would just follow the 302. With Ajax it looks like it is just getting the 302 then you need to follow it.